# Append session id with query string at the time of button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

I like to append session id with query string at the time of button click and it will redirects another page in asp.net.I tried lot..but

```
Session["uname"] = null;
Session["pwd"] = null;
Session["lout"] = "a";
Response.Redirect("Login1.aspx?sid=" + Session["lout"].ToString(),true);
```

And I used following code in page load of `login.aspx`

```
if (Convert.ToString(Session["lout"]).Equals("a"))
{
    lout.Text = "Logged Out Successfully ";

}
```

Comment: Please write a better title, re-format your code and add more explanation. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the other page that is redirecting to? your code does not provide enough detail. Try to add more detail and code to be clear what is the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the sid as query string so you can read the query string instead of :

```
Convert.ToString(Session["lout"]).Equals("a")
```

You can use `Request.QueryString("sid")`

I don't know what is the issue with your code above. It also has to work. But if you are calling `Session.Abandon` before redirecting, then all the session values will be getting cleared.